# Why false == "false" is false?

Tags: javascript

I am still learning the basics of javaScript and I don't understand why this happens.

Having type coercion `false == "false"`would be converted into:

```
false == false //true
```

or

```
"false" == "false" //true
```

So, why `false == "false"` is false?

Comment: because one of them is a boolean an the other is a string.

Comment: Thank you:):) I've just tried `true == "true"` and results `false`. Very fast answer:)

Comment: Data type are different , one is boolean and one is string

Comment: @viery365, check the second table here (pretty much Quentin's answer): https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you:) Excellent tables:)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Your comment isn't even correct. `==` attempts to perform a type conversion... so saying "one is a string and the other is a boolean" is not really the case here. It just so happens the type conversions end up not being equivalent in the end.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You've misunderstood the [type conversion rules](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3). `false` doesn't get converted to a string before comparison.

> If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.

`false` is converted to a number, which gives:

```
+0 == "false"
```

… then …

> If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String,
>   return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

… `"false"` is converted to a number, which gives:

```
+0 == NaN
```

… which is false.

Comment: Is this answer I was looking for. I must understand better the rules of type coercion. Of course I am thinking always to use === but I needed to understand this. Thank you:) I will accept the answer in few minutes.

Comment: And hence false === "0" would result into true.

Comment: @sahaj Thank you!:) Yes, now I understand:)

Comment: @sahaj - Not with `===` it won't.

Comment: Yes, excuse me for the typo error. It should be ==. i.e. false == "0" would result into true.

Comment: @nnnnnn Oh yes, using == of course, I didn't notice it:)

Comment: @Quentin How does ToNumber("string") gets converted to NaN ? More importantly, how can I check this in a console ? Is there a way ?

Comment: @FlyingGambit — The short answer is "because that is what the spec says" (and I linked to the spec in the answer). You can't really check that in the console because it happens in the middle of the processing of a single operator. You can only see what happens at the two ends. (You could manually convert to a number with `+"false"` and see `NaN` though).

Comment: @Quentin I think I got it, its basically like comparing between `+false == +"false"` which is the same as `0 == NaN`, this according to ECMA rules returns `false`.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is because "false" is a string (as Gerardo Furado pointed out in the comments), the test you are making is equivalent to false = "hello".

Javascript does not look at the word in the string to determine if it is a boolean and then try to get the value from that.

Note:

In general in javascript it is now preferred that you use the === operator, to avoid all of this.

Answer (score 1):

```
false == "false" // false
```

because, the boolean false is converted into 0, so, we compare 0 with "false" and the output is false

Answer (score -4):

These are different kind of items. 
`"string"` and `boolean`.

So:

```
false.toString() == "false"
```

Comment: Using double equals this would always be true no matter what string is on the right side.